# How to revert recent underline change in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, appearance

Today I updated Google Chrome, from version `36.0.1985.143` to `37.0.2062.102` which introduced a strange rendering change. It seems that for anchor links, the spacing between the bottom of the link text and its underline (text decoration) is one pixel less than previously:

[image]

For me personally, this just looks awful. Can anyone tell me, if this is a bug or a new feature?

Additionally the most important thing I would like to know is if there is any way to revert or disable this change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Font rendering

It's a *feature*. Actually, it's not just the underline. For example, compare the `0` before and after: they're slightly different. By zooming the picture you can spot other subtle differences:

[image]

The [subpixel rendering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering) is not the same, as hinted by the changelog (bold emphasis mine):

> Chrome 37.0.2062.94 contains a number of fixes and improvements, including:
>
> - **DirectWrite support on Windows for improved font rendering**
> - A number of new apps/extension APIs
> - Lots of under the hood changes for stability and performance
>
> A full list of changes is available in the [log](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+log/36.0.1985.0..37.0.2062.0?pretty=full).
>
> <sub>Source: [Chrome Releases: Stable Channel Update](http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.it/2014/08/stable-channel-update_26.html)</sub>

The change was aimed for the better, but it got mixed reactions because not everybody experienced a real improvement. Granted, the hardware and software combinations definitely play a major role here, so your mileage may vary.

### Reverting back

If you don't like the changes, you can try disabling [DirectWrite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectWrite) as a workaround:

1. Type or paste the following address in the Chrome address bar:

   ```
   chrome://flags/#disable-direct-write
   ```
2. Turn off the DirectWrite feature. Restart the browser to apply the changes.

**Note** The steps above apply to version `37.0.2062.102`; newer versions might require a different approach. Since DirectWrite is only available in Windows Vista and later, the old GDI-based rendering engine could be removed entirely after [XP support ends in April 2015](http://chrome.blogspot.it/2013/10/extending-chrome-support-for-xp-users.html).

### Further reading

- [Introducing DirectWrite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371554%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: It's a broken feature, for sure. Pretty much every site I use has had some problems with fonts, and it sucks even more for commercial products, because we can't actually affect this since this is completely client-side.

Comment: @and31415, Sure it's a "feature", but it's actually a feature that makes things look uglier.

Comment: This new "feature" made me wipe my monitor thinking there's dirt on it today: https://i.imgur.com/MoFSMsU.png